# ICS file is not Auto Scheduling event to google calendar

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar

Currently I'm attaching an ICS file to an email and needing it to auto schedule an event on a google calendar.  I know this is possible since I've tested it with Outlook and I see the event on my google calendar without me opening up the email.  Currently the email auto-schedules for Outlook and Yahoo.  Gmail seems to be the one that it currently doesn't auto-schedule.  There is a "Add to my calendar" button but I need it to auto-schedule the event.

1. Is the ICS file the reason it gets auto Scheduled?
2. If it is the ICS file, what is needed in an ICS file for google to auto-schedule an event.

Comment: So the difference is the home grown ics file?  (IE you've got auto add to calendar ticked in google and you are emailing the main google account email?).  Have you tested it against the various ics validators? Have you compared it against the one generated by outllook for differences?

Comment: I'm using a file that I got from an outlook meeting invite that worked through outlook.  I'm trying to do everything that Outlook does but I seem to be missing something. I got an error on some lines being too long so I fixed that and passed the iCalendar validator but now googles not even picking up that there is a ics file in the email.

Comment: Validators not 100% - different ones report different things. Try a few. Also do you have the file headers correct? Text/calendar etc

Answer (score 0):

Invite the attendees in the ics file. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.1, Don't just send the ics file.

Comment: Sorry if I missed something.  I'm not sure if I understand what to add to the attendee section.  Do you have an example?  I didn't see one that had invite in the link above.

Comment: Do you have for each attendee:

ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=
 TRUE;CN=.......

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.  There was something wrong in the file I was using to test with so I switched to a simpler file with less section in it.  I then added a ContentType header, the ATTENDEE section, and made sure there were no line breaks on each of the sections.  After that, it started working.  Thank you so much Anmari for all of your help.